# How can a servlet pass back to the browser the entire content of a proxied login result?

Tags: java, http, servlets

I promised to do something, but my managers want assurance that it can be done. What seems like a simple task is surprisingly hard to find example of.  It consists of:

1. The browser asks a Java servlet for access to a remote site.
2. The servlet opens a HttpUrlConnection to that remote site.
3. The servlet sends a login request to that remote site.
4. The servlet receives a login form.
5. The servlet populates the login form from user session data, then
   POSTs it.
6. The servlet receives the "welcome" from the remote site, complete
   with headers and cookies.
7. The request of step 1 is finally filled by the content, headers, and cookies from step 6.

I'm having trouble getting code examples, leading me to think that what I want to do can't be accomplished.  Can someone point me to an example?

Thanks,

Jerome.

Comment: Can this be done using SSO solution rather than you coding it on your own?

Comment: Funny you ask. My server manages its own logins, but now must communicate with a SAML identity provider so it can then access a federated service provider without showing the user yet another login page. This "remote site" will be the IdP and its login page. This architecture is what my time budget can afford.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the **domain** of the session cookie.

More accurately, the question is what you're planning **next** after step 7.
Say your servlet is at "https://mycompany.com/loginServlet", and the remote site is a toy store "https://toys.com". Were you hoping that after step 7, the browser could be redirected to "https://toys.com" and get a proper service befitting a logged-in user? This won't work because when the browser received a session cookie from "mycompany.com" (in step7), this cookie will be attached to further requests for "mycompany.com" -  but not to "toys.com", it's a security feature for excellent reason.

**In short, this approach might work if both the servlet and the toys site are on the same domain**. Though it makes me a bit uncomfortable in terms of security and password management, but never mind. 
Obviously this approach would also work in the (unrealistic) case of letting your server proxy all further requests from the browser to "toys.com", but that's unrealistic for a typical commercial site (due to relative/absolute links, ajaxes etc.).

If it's different domains, then I second the wise comment made by "Rahul B" above: please look into SSO, and/or check with "toys.com" what login mechanisms they offer - maybe they already have something like "login with google" that's convenient enough.

Comment: The domains would likely be "biz.mycompany.com" and "sso.mycompany.com".  It looks like the cookie domain will be "sso.mycompany.com". This seems OK, as the cookie is set by the IdP for browser access to it, to look up a cached login.  Because all of this is the SAML world, the toys.com SAML service receives the IdP's authentication assertion, trusts this browser and sends the browser its own session cookies.